# How to get JS to read the code thrown by PHP die

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

My JS function expects a certain return from the PHP code in case of a failure.

```
function showResult(data) 
{
    if (data == 'save_failed') {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Unfortunately, we were not able to save your information. Please contact an admin.';
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#notify").clearForm().clearFields().resetForm();
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Thank you for signing up with us.';
        return false;
    }
}
```

This works fin when I `echo 'save_failed';` in case of an explicit error, but it does not work in the case of die statements, such as this one:

```
mysql_connect("host", "user", "pass") or die('save_failed');
```

I entered a wrong hostname but the JS function did not receive the `'save_failed'` return.

PHP script:

```
if (!(empty($_POST['name']) && empty($_POST['email'])))
    {
        //sanitizing inputs for MySQL insertion
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

        //connecting to db
        mysql_connect("host", "user", "pass") or die('save_failed');
        mysql_select_db("table") or die('save_failed');

        //inserting into table
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO notify (name, email) VALUES('" . $name . "', '" . $email . "' ) ") 
        or die('save_failed');  

    }
    else
    {
        echo 'save_failed';
    }
```

Comment: Tip: use a browser debugging tool such us Firebug to see the exact output generated by your PHP script.

Comment: Posting the php script would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though `die("save_failed")` will output "save_failed", it will not stop any previous output in your script from being sent.

Ensure that if you go to the script yourself then you are receiving just "save_failed" in the page source and no erroneous characters

Comment: You were correct. I had some debugging module installed which was sending out a ton of diagnostic information along with `save_failed`.

Answer (score 2):

I would propose another strategy in dealing with errors.

1. Use [output buffering](http://de.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) to ensure no data will be send to client (eg. the beginning of a HTML-Document)
2. Start using [Exceptions](http://ralphschindler.com/2010/09/15/exception-best-practices-in-php-5-3). They represent fatal errors, but with the ability to determine the exact line and parameters the error occurred.
3. The Browser tries to evaluate the type of response based on the content type header. If you want it to display simple text use

   header('Content-Type: text/plain');
4. Use a global [Exception handler](http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-exception-handler.php), to transform the messages the way you like.

Works for me! Most servers have enough power today to use these, little more advanced methods.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to use die to pass some information to the page. Normally, there will be  other data in the response string.

An easier way is to embed PHP code in your JS code. An example will be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   data = "<?php echo('Save Failed'); ?>";
</script>
```